# Powershell Get-ADUser filter to exclude specific OU in the list

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, powershell-4.0, windows-scripting

I am trying to change the below Powershell script so it does not search any account in the specific OU from the list.

The AD account that will be reported is the AD account without any of the below attributes:

```
Phone Number
Mobile/Cellphone Number
Job Title
Email Address.
Company
City
office address
```

This is the script that I have so far:

```
    $filter = "(Enabled -eq 'true') -and (mail -notlike '*') -and (company -notlike '*') -and "
$filter += "(l -notlike '*') -and (physicalDeliveryOfficeName -notlike '*') -and "
$filter += "(title -notlike '*') -and (telephoneNumber -notlike '*') -and (mobile -notlike '*')"

$properties = @('mail', 'physicalDeliveryOfficeName', 'Company', 'DisplayName', 'title', 'SamAccountName', 'CanonicalName', 'lastlogondate', 'mobile', 'telephoneNumber', 'l', 'Whencreated', 'DistinguishedName')
$domainDN = (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName

$excludeOUs = @(
'OU=Disabled Users,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com'
    'OU=GlobalCorp Testing,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com'
    'OU=Admin Accounts,OU=GlobalCorp Global,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com'
    'OU=Service Accounts,OU=GlobalCorp Global,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com'
    'OU=Shared Mailboxes,OU=GlobalCorp Global,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com'
)

$reExcludeOUs = '(?:{0})$' -f ($excludeOUs -join '|')

Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties $properties -SearchBase $domainDN |
    Where-Object {
        ($_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $reExcludeOUs) -and
        ($_.SamAccountName -notmatch '^(SM_|Temp|HealthMailbox)|SVC|Test|admin|\$') -and
        ($_.DisplayName -notmatch 'Admin|Calendar|Room')
    } |
    Select-Object -Property `
        DisplayName,
        Company,
        Title,
        TelephoneNumber,
        Mobile,
        PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName,
        SamAccountName,
        Mail,
        @{n = 'OU'; e = { $_.CanonicalName.Remove($_.CanonicalName.LastIndexOf($_.Name) - 1) } },
        @{n = 'CN'; e = { Split-Path $_.CanonicalName -Parent } },
        @{n = 'ParentContainer'; e = { $_.DistinguishedName -replace '^CN=.*?(?=CN|OU)' } },
        LastLogondate,
        WhenCreated | 
        Sort-Object OU | 
        ConvertTo-HTML | 
        Set-Variable HTMLBody

Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer SMTP.GlobalCo.com -From "$env:COMPUTERNAME@$env:userdnsdomain" -To Admin@MSP.com -Subject "AD User Incomplete report as at $((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy'))" -Body ($HTMLBody -join '`n') -BodyAsHTML
```

How can I modify the above Where-Object filter?

Comment: `-notcontains` means that the right-hand _item_ is not in the left-hand _collection_ ... but you have them reversed. [*grin*] try `-notin` instead.

Comment: Already did change it into using ($_.DistinguishedName -notin "*$excludeOUs*"), but the result is still the same?

Comment: Your variable `$excludeOUs` results in OU DN's ending in a comma. Create the array simply by comma separating the values like `$excludeOUs = 'OU=Disabled Users,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com', 'OU=GlobalCorp Testing,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com', ..`

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer - your posted code STILL shows >>> `($_.DistinguishedName -notcontains $excludeOUs)`<<< ... if you want accurate help, you will need to post the code you are actually discussing ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is that you say you want to report only users that are *without any of the below attributes*. In that case, your filter is wrong and should be more like:

```
$filter =  "(Enabled -eq 'true') -and (mail -notlike '*') -and (company -notlike '*') -and "
$filter += "(l -notlike '*') -and (physicalDeliveryOfficeName -notlike '*') -and "
$filter += "(title -notlike '*') -and (telephoneNumber -notlike '*') -and (mobile -notlike '*')"
```

<sup>I've spread this out on several lines to make it more readable</sup>

Then there is the way you construct your `$excludeOUs` that adds a comma after each OU DN.
I would suggest to simply declare that as string array like this:

```
$excludeOUs = 'OU=Disabled Users,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com', 
    'OU=GlobalCorp Testing,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com',
    'OU=Admin Accounts,OU=GlobalCorp Global,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com',
    'OU=Service Accounts,OU=GlobalCorp Global,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com',
    'OU=Shared Mailboxes,OU=GlobalCorp Global,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com'
```

and for testing purposes later on, combine them to create a Regular Expression:

```
# create a regular expression string combining the OUs with the 'OR' pipe symbol and wrap that
# inside a non-capturing group. The $ means the match should end in any of the 'OR'-ed ou DNs
$reExcludeOUs = '(?:{0})$' -f ($excludeOUs -join '|')
```

Armed with that, you can do

```
$properties = 'EmailAddress', 'Office', 'Company', 'DisplayName', 'Title', 'SamAccountName', 'DistinguishedName',
              'CanonicalName', 'LastLogonDate', 'MobilePhone', 'OfficePhone','City','Created'
$domainDN = (Get-ADDomain).DistinguishedName

$report = Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties $properties -SearchBase $domainDN |
            Where-Object {
                ($_.DisplayName -notmatch 'Admin|Calendar|Room') -and
                ($_.SamAccountName -notmatch '^(SM_|HealthMailbox)|SVC|Test|admin|\$') -and
                ($_.DistinguishedName -notmatch $reExcludeOUs)
            } |
            Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Company, Title, OfficePhone, MobilePhone,
                                    Office, SamAccountName, EmailAddress, City,
                                    @{n = "OU"; e = { $_.CanonicalName.Remove($_.CanonicalName.LastIndexOf($_.Name) - 1) } },
                                    @{n = 'CN'; e = { Split-Path $_.CanonicalName -Parent } },
                                    @{n = 'ParentContainer'; e = { $_.DistinguishedName -replace '^CN=.*?(?=CN|OU)' } },
                                    LastLogonDate, Created
```

After this, the `$report` variable should contain all info you need to save as CSV, ConvertToHTML etc.

<sup>Inside the `Where-Object{}` you can use regular expression matches (`-notmatch` in this case), so one regex can save you a lot of `-notlike` clauses here.</sup>

<sup>P.S. for cmdlets like the `Send-MailMessage` with a lot of parameters I'd advise to use [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-6) to keep the code readable.</sup>

Hope that helps

Comment: OK, somehow when I execute the updated code above, it is still returning some of the users that are in the excluded OU list?

Comment: How is that possible to interrogate the AD users that is NOT the member of the specific OU listed?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Can you give examples of those users? (The sanitized DistinghuishedNames). Do any of your OUs to be excluded have spacial characters like a backslash?

Comment: This is the example of the OU list:
    'OU=GlobalCorp Testing,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com',
    'OU=HeadOffice,OU=Shared Mailboxes,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com',

    'OU=Branch1,OU=Shared Mailboxes,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com',
    'OU=Branch2,OU=Shared Mailboxes,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com',
    'OU=Branch3,OU=Shared Mailboxes,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com',
 
    'OU=Service Accounts,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com',
    'OU=Service Accounts,OU=Users,OU=Branch1,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com',
    'OU=Service Accounts,OU=Users,OU=Branch2,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com',
    'OU=Service Accounts,OU=Users,OU=Branch3,DC=GlobalCorp,DC=com',

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer Yes, those are the DN's of the OUs, but you say some users that are in any of these OU's still get processed, so what is really interesting is to see one or two DistinghuishedNames of such **users**

Answer (score 1):

You can use both `-notcontains` or `-notmatch`, but the problem here is that you have to select the *DistinguishedName* too otherwise it will not apply the condition because it's 'invisible'

```
Get-ADUser -Filter $filter -Properties $properties -SearchBase $domainDN |
    Select-Object -Property `
        DisplayName,
        Company,
        Title,
        telephoneNumber,
        mobile,
        PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName,
        DistinguishedName,
        ...
        ...
```